# Failure on apt-get Ubuntu 14.0.4 on ftp get vimos-kit-2.9.9.tar.gz

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I want to apt-get install astyle. When I go to do this, I get the following error:

```
Setting up cpl-plugin-vimos-calib (2.9.9+dfsg-2) 
--2015-12-02 16:35:24-- ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/pipelines/vimo/vimos-  kit-2.9.9.tar.gz
=> ‘-’
Resolving ftp.eso.org (ftp.eso.org)... 134.171.42.54, 134.171.42.53
Connecting to ftp.eso.org (ftp.eso.org)|134.171.42.54|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/dfs/pipelines/vimos ... done.
==> SIZE vimos-kit-2.9.9.tar.gz ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR vimos-kit-2.9.9.tar.gz ... 
No such file ‘vimos-kit-2.9.9.tar.gz’.
```

I have another install of the same system where this error does not occur. I looked at the ftp site ftp.eso.org and I could find later versions of vimos but not this specific version. Has anybody run into this and is there a workaround? Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Ranga

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg4803183.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to patch my ubuntu? Upgrading is not an option for me at the moment.